# What is controlling x axis value in this highcharts example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In this highchart : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-basic/

What is causing the x axis values to appear in years increasing by +10 for each point ?

I can see point start is set to 1940 and xAxis is configured to return this.value but there appears to be some implicit functionality computing the value for each year ?

What to change to display time range over 12 months of year instead of 1940 - 2000... ?
Fiddle code :

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 1940,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USA',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
        }, {
            name: 'USSR/Russia',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
        }]
    });
});
```

Update : how to explicitly supply x values to chart ?

Comment: the data points each represent one year. So the only thing controlling the x axis, after the pointStart is set, are the data points, and Highchart's standard axis and tick scaling.  To change it to show 12 months, there are a variety of things that you can do - you need to be more specific about exactly what you want. You can use categories that use month names, You can simply have 12 data points that result in numbers 1-12 on the axis, you can use a datetime axis type along with a pointStart and pointInterval, you can explicitly supply x values to the chart, etc...

Comment: See the 2nd fiddle posted in my answer below, to provide dates as x values to the chart explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the issues from my comment:

1) Use a `datetime` x axis type, and either supply a `pointStart` and `pointInterval`

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ot24zrkt/1/

Or supply x values explicitly:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ot24zrkt/2/

(the dates can either by a Date.UTC object [remember, javascript counts months starating at 0], or an epoch time stamp [in milliseconds] references:  http://www.epochconverter.com/ | http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp )

2) Use categories:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ot24zrkt/3/

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following changes:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            type: 'datetime',

            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000*24*30,

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared:true,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {

                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USA',
            pointInterval: 3600 * 1000*24*30,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(1940, 0, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
        }, {
            name: 'USSR/Russia',
            pointInterval: 3600 * 1000*24*30,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(1940, 0, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
        }]
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5qfauzy2/)

hope it works..